# NuGet package installation failed because path too long

Tags: visual-studio, windows-11

I'm trying to install a NuGet package in my `MAUI` solution with Visual Studio. In particular, I like to install [Plugin.Firebase](https://github.com/TobiasBuchholz/Plugin.Firebase). The error I get is the following one

> Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\enric.nuget\packages\xamarin.firebase.ios.installations\8.10.0.3\lib\net6.0-ios15.4\Firebase.Installations.resources\FirebaseInstallations.xcframework\ios-arm64_x86_64-simulator\FirebaseInstallations.framework\Headers\FirebaseInstallations-umbrella.h'.

I think the issue is coming from the long path. So, I changed the registry with

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem" `
-Name "LongPathsEnabled" -Value 1 -PropertyType DWORD -Force
```

restarted the machine, checking the change was applying in the registry. Unfortunately, this error is still coming up.